# No estoy pudiendo renderizar el nombre de los usuarios haciendo pull de una API

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

Estoy usando React Native, no me esta llamando al valor de first_name desde la API que estoy usando que es esta https://reqres.in/

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, FlatList } from "react-native";
import axios from "axios";

export default function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({hits: []});

  useEffect(async () => {
    const result = await axios('https://reqres.in/api/users');
    setUser(result.data);
  });

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <FlatList
          data={user}
          renderItem={(userItem) => (
            <View>
              <Text>{`${userItem.first_name} ${userItem.last_name}`}</Text>
            </View>
          )}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';

export default function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const result = axios
      .get('https://reqres.in/api/users')
      .then(result => setUser(result.data.data));
  }, []);

  return (
    <View>
      <FlatList
        data={user}
        renderItem={({item: userItem}) =>
          (
            <View>
              <Text>{`${userItem.first_name} ${userItem.last_name}`}</Text>
            </View>
          )
        }
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Con estas modificaciones debería funcionar. Como referencia, te dejo este [link](https://github.com/axios/axios#response-schema) donde podes ver el response schema de axios (los datos retornados por el server se encuentran dentro de `data`), también cómo utilizar el prop [renderItem](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#renderitem) del FlatList de react-native, donde agregué el destructure adecuado.